# cleaned up resubmitted another form validate php javascript parse error

Tags: php

I cleaned up and this is error:

```
// validation expected data exists
if (!isset($_POST['name'])) { ||
    /* !isset($_POST['last_name']) || */
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    /* !isset($_POST['telephone']) || */
    !isset($_POST['comments']) 
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
```

The error says:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR in /home/kcorchid/public_html/Tap/Send_Comments.php on line 37 ...

The line is:

```
if (!isset($_POST['name'])) { ||
```

Answer (score 1):

Reusable and easily changeable:

```
$must_exist = array('name','email','comments','last_name','telephone');

foreach ($must_exist as $item) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$item])) {
        die('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }
}

// if code executes past this point, all the $must_exist items were found
```

Comment: thanx for your attn but i got error message even when filled out..
thanx for your help tho

Comment: I suggest you check what you are getting back from the form.  Try `var_dump($_POST);die();` and make sure the required fields are all there

Answer (score 0):

You just got a brace in the wrong place:

```
if (!isset($_POST['name']) ||
                                               /*!isset($_POST['last_name']) || */
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
                                               /*!isset($_POST['telephone']) || */
    !isset($_POST['comments']) )
{
    die('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
}
```

Should work just fine!

Comment: thanx, now it tells me on same line::

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR in /home/kcorchid/public_html/Tap/Send_Comments.php on line 37

Comment: @user2229604 Sorry the first version had an error in it. Note that unless you have function called `died` the standard PHP one is `die`.

Comment: i changed all "died" to " die " etc... it probably should work, but doesnt..thank you tho..